# How to generate a minimal allowed document using Xerces-C?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces, xerces-c

I haven't find how to create a default document from XML Schema in Xerces-C documentation. Still I've tried the following:

```
const char XMLLinesSchema[] = /* some valid schema */;
MemBufInputSource schema_mem_buf( reinterpret_cast<const XMLByte*>(XMLLinesSchema),
    sizeof(XMLLinesSchema), L"schema" );
XercesDOMParser parser;
// enable schema processing
parser.setDoSchema( true );
parser.setDoNamespaces( true );
// Let's preparse the schema grammar (.xsd) and cache it.
parser.loadGrammar( schema_mem_buf, Grammar::SchemaGrammarType, true );
parser.useCachedGrammarInParse( true );
parser.setValidationScheme( XercesDOMParser::Val_Always );

DOMDocument* doc = parser.getDocument();
```

But `parser.getDocument` returns `NULL`. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to generate a minimal allowed document for the specified XML Schema using Xerces-C?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says this:

> It should be used by applications which choose to parse and process
>   the XML document using the DOM api's.

You're using a parser so it expects some input to parse, through the [parse(...)](http://software.decisionsoft.com/oldsite/doxygen/pathan2/classAbstractDOMParser.html#z357_0) function.  You've parsed nothing, so nothing will be returned.

Comment: What should I use instead of `XercesDOMParser`?

Comment: I think you'll need to look at using `DOMDOMImplementation::createDocument()` for creating a default document, and IIRC, you can set schema etc there too.